# Google font doesn't work in https html page

Tags: html, fonts, https

Google font doesn't work in https html page.

Hopefully there is a solution on this.

Comment: you can use font url like //fonts.googleapis.com/....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of implementing google font in https site/page.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```